# stop Unslider scrolling when under a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, modalviewcontroller

I come from the UI design side... but can usually implement basic javascript and jQuery plugins when I need them. In this case I have Unslider running as a feature sideshow with links to a shadowbox pop-up window. I would like the scrolling animation to stop when the modal window is in view.

Also, I'd like to have the slides rotate vertically... but that's less of an issue at the mo.

Any help would be appreciated. I just spent the last half hour reading past threads and didn't find what I was looking for there.

The site: http://www.zacharysequoia.com

Comment: Unslider has a `.stop()` method to pause the slideshow when needed. Its right there on the home page - http://unslider.com/

Comment: how do I attach that to the opening of the shadowbox, and then start it again when the shadowbox is gone?

Comment: Bind `.stop()` to the click event of all links inside any of the slider's `<li>`s. Similarly, bind `.start()` to shadowbox's close event. Of course you'll need to figure out the details.

Comment: Cheers. That's harder for me than for you... back to the search bar :)

Comment: OK... having trouble figuring this out. Any chance of a hint? :)

Comment: 2 mins. Let me figure out first :)

Comment: Well.. `.stop()` seems to be doing nothing!

Comment: I've commented around what I've done at the bottom of the index page source. Not working for me.

Comment: @techfoobar did you mean that the .stop function is not working within the Unslider plugin?

Comment: Yes, stop() seems to be doing nothing.